# Font extension causes Swift live preview to crash (Xcode 12.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, live-preview

I've tried to create Font extension for my application like this:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Font {
    // H1
    static var largeTitle: Font {
        return Font.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 34)
    }
    
    // H2
    static var title: Font {
        return Font.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 24)
    }

    // Body 2 (input title)
    static var caption: Font {
        return Font.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 14)
    }

...
```

The font is applying correctly in simulator. But live preview crashes with the following error in diagnostic window

```
ambiguous use of 'caption'

----------------------------------------

CompileDylibError: Failed to build LoginView.swift

Compiling failed: ambiguous use of 'caption'

/src/Login/LoginView.swift:31:31: error: ambiguous use of 'caption'
                        .font(Font.caption)
                              ^
/src/Font.swift:38:16: note: found this candidate
    static var caption: Font {
               ^
SwiftUI.Font:14:23: note: found this candidate
    public static var caption: Font
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Font` already has a static property called `caption`. See [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/caption). You should not be able to add a property with the same name and type, that piece of code should not compile at all.

You need to rename your property to resolve the ambiguity.

The same applies to `title` and `largeTitle`, you shouldn't recreate properties that already exist on `Font`, you should rename all of them.

Unrelated to your question, but no need to add those properties as computed properties, they can be immutable stored properties.

```
extension Font {
    // H1
    static let robotoLargeTitle = Font.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 34)
    
    // H2
    static let robotoTitle = Font.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 24)

    // Body 2 (input title)
    static let robotoCaption = Font.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 14)
}
```